# How to get CSS of a clicked div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anybody know how to get **border-color** of a div using jQuery.

```js
$("#divcolor").click(function (){
  alert("dsf");
  var divcolor = $(this).css("border-color");
  alert(divcolor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divcolor" style="border:#333333 solid 1px;" >
 This is the target
</div>
```

In `divcolor` variable I am not getting anything.

Comment: Looks good to me .. except for I have some wierd feeling about #333333 being there for the color, I don't if JQuery returns that. Just speaking out loud. Thanks

Comment: I think by using JavaScript Reference we can get those style properties easily. 
http://codepunk.hardwar.org.uk/css2js.htm

Comment: Thanks to all for helping me to finding the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the CSS jQuery function like you did:

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#name

But read this paragraph:

*Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.*

Comment: @Mike background-color is coming but border-color is not coming.

Comment: Why was this answer chosen? It seems it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is elsewhere. That code works on Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

`border-color` isn't working for me either (on Firefox), but this works:

```
$(this).css("border-top-color")
```

http://jsbin.com/ezefu

Comment: @Kobi: I was curious to know how JQuery would get the color for different sides of the border, your answer clears this a bit :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
$("#divcolor").click(function (){
  alert("dsf");
  var divcolor = $(this).css("border-color");
  alert(divcolor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divcolor" style="border:1px solid; border-color:#333333;" >
  This is the target
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divcolor").click(function (){
  var divcolor = $(this).css("borderColor");
  alert(divcolor);
});
```

Comment: Good idea, though it gives me the four values: `rgb(51, 51, 51) rgb(51, 51, 51) rgb(51, 51, 51) rgb(51, 51, 51)`

Comment: Well, you can get the hex value by saying parseInt((a*256*256)+(b*256)+c, 16) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I always consider it better practice to work with CSS classes instead of CSS direct. Then you could have something like:

```
$(this).hasClass("MyClassWithTheBorderColorStyleInIt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
$("#divcolor").click(function() {
  var divcolor = $(this).css("border");
  divcolor = divcolor.substring((divcolor.indexOf(' ') + 1), divcolor.length);
  divcolor = divcolor.substring((divcolor.indexOf(' ') + 1), divcolor.length);
  alert(divcolor);
});
```

Comment: But this will be applicable only when you are writing shorthand notations. The best practice is to use different class, as said earlier :)